# Objects Array Get Specific Object and display together PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am facing a problem problem here and need some help.

I have saved in my database a json_aray array with objects.

After decoding and `print_r` it I get this result.

```
Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Image 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => url.jpg ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Image 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => url.jpg )     
[2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Accommodation 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => image.jpg ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Accommodation 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => image.jpg ) 
[4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Accommodation 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => image.jpg ) 
[5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Image 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => image.jpg )     
[6] => stdClass Object ( 
    [Title] => Location 
    [Info] => info
    [ImageURL] => image.jpg )     
)
```

So here is the **CASE:**

I am trying to create a div for every different `Object->Title` e.g

I tried to check that with `foreach` loop but the result was creating 5 different `divs` instead of one.

Is there any built-in function in php to get all the `$obj->Info` if the `$obj->Title == 'foo'` or somehow check before the `foreach` loop what data the array has and separate them?

What i did in my code is below

```
   while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($get_details)) {
        $a = $row['additionalInformation'];
        $b = json_decode($a);
        $c = $b->AdditonalInfo;
        foreach ($c as $d){ 
            echo '<div class="class">';
            if(($d->Title !== 'Image')){
                echo '<h2>'.$d->Title.'</h2>';
                echo '<p>'.$d->Info.'</p>';
            }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

1. Change my code with the actual one
2. This is what I get

[image]

But I need to create Accommodation or every same `Title` just once and all `Info` that has `Title == 'Accommodation'` under that div.

IF my question is clear enough please let me know so I can update it.

**So to sum up i need to display all `[Info]` that has same `[Title]` in one div and create different div for each unique '[Title]'**

Thanks In Advance

Comment: `<h4><?=$value->Title?></h4>` just remove the shorthand echo php tags, you're already inside the php space just concatenate the variable

Comment: Yes I know, edit mistake. Thanks

Comment: Unclear, you output all data where `Title` has required value. What else do you need?

Comment: and shouldn't that be `$value->Title == 'Accommodation'`, in your code `$d` is undefined

Comment: Try checking if it is going inside if or not.

Comment: @Ghost I updated my question and added an image so you can see what I get actually and what I am asking for. Thanks

Comment: @u_mulder can you please check updated question?

Comment: @SambhajiKatrajkar can you please check updated question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirements: Show 'nested groups' in a sequential stream of records.
Here we have a nested group indicated by a field called 'Title'.

The input records must be sorted so that all the records in each group are together and in the required order.

Now, the first thought is to use a 'foreach' loop. This is not the clearest approach because you cannot detect the end of the group by looking at the current record. Also, the foreach loop reads the next record at the end of the loop. So,  you end up trying to work out where you are in the group to know what to do.

I use a technique called 'read ahead'. The idea is to read a record before the loop and the read the next record immediately after you have processed the current one. The 'trick' is that you process all the records in a group inside a loop.

So, the logic is an iteration of:

- Process start of group - already has the first record of the group - important.
- Process all the detail records belonging to the group - records are read inside this loop.
- Process the end of the group - the current record is the first of the next group
- repeat for each group.

It results in easier to understand code.

I have split all the separate actions into function so that you easily modify the individual actions.

Notice the code matches the structure of the data. There is always one place in the code to put the required action for that particular data item.

### [Full working Source Code at eval.in](https://eval.in/1013212)

### Run the code

```
outputAllGroups($src);
exit();
```

### Process All the Groups

```
function outputAllGroups(&$inputList) 
{
    reset($inputList);  
    $currentDetails = current($inputList); // read the first record 

    while ($currentDetails !== false) { // not end of records

        // start the title group
        $currentTitle = $currentDetails->Title; 
        outputGroupHeader($currentDetails);

        // process all records in the group
        while (    $currentDetails !== false 
                && $currentDetails->Title === $currentTitle) { 

            outputDetails($currentDetails);

            $currentDetails = readNextDetails($inputList); // may end group
        }

        // end the title group 
        outputGroupFooter($currentTitle);
    }
}
```

### Functions for the individual actions

```
function outputGroupHeader($details)
{
    echo '<div class="TitleGroup">'. "<!-- Start Group: {$details->Title} -->". PHP_EOL
       . '<div class="Title">'. $details->Title .'</div>' . PHP_EOL; 
}

function outputGroupFooter($title)
{
    echo '</div>'. "<!-- End Group: {$title}  -->". PHP_EOL;
}

function outputDetails($details)
{
    echo '<div class="details">'. PHP_EOL,  
            $details->Info . PHP_EOL,  
            $details->ImageURL .PHP_EOL,
         '</div>' . PHP_EOL;            
}

function readNextDetails(&$inputList)
{
    $allOk = next($inputList); // advance next
    return $allOk !== false ? current($inputList) : $allOk; // advance next
}
```

### Output

```
<div class="TitleGroup"><!-- Start Group: Image -->
<div class="Title">Image</div>
<div class="details">
info1
url1.jpg
</div>
<div class="details">
info2
url2.jpg
</div>
</div><!-- End Group: Image  -->
<div class="TitleGroup"><!-- Start Group: Accommodation -->
<div class="Title">Accommodation</div>
<div class="details">
info3
image3.jpg
</div>
<div class="details">
info4
image4.jpg
</div>
<div class="details">
info5
image5.jpg
</div>
</div><!-- End Group: Accommodation  -->
<div class="TitleGroup"><!-- Start Group: Image -->
<div class="Title">Image</div>
<div class="details">
info6
image6.jpg
</div>
</div><!-- End Group: Image  -->
<div class="TitleGroup"><!-- Start Group: Location -->
<div class="Title">Location</div>
<div class="details">
info7
image7.jpg
</div>
</div><!-- End Group: Location  -->
```

### Data

```
$src = Array ( 
    '0' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Image', 
        'Info' => 'info1',
        'ImageURL' => 'url1.jpg', ), 
    '1' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Image', 
        'Info' => 'info2',
        'ImageURL' => 'url2.jpg', ),     
    '2' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Accommodation', 
        'Info' => 'info3',
        'ImageURL' => 'image3.jpg', ), 
    '3' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Accommodation', 
        'Info' => 'info4',
        'ImageURL' => 'image4.jpg', ), 
    '4' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Accommodation', 
        'Info' => 'info5',
        'ImageURL' => 'image5.jpg', ), 
    '5' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Image', 
        'Info' => 'info6',
        'ImageURL' => 'image6.jpg', ),     
    '6' => (object) array( 
        'Title' => 'Location', 
        'Info' => 'info7',
        'ImageURL' => 'image7.jpg', ),     
    );
```

Comment: Thank you @Ryan Vincent. Especially for the big explanation, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do so to get for each result unique div. For the 2 quetion (Is there any built-in function in php to get all the $obj->Info if the $obj->Title == 'foo' or somehow check before the foreach loop what data the array has and separate them?) I will find some solution late :)

```
$a = $row['additionalInformation'];
$b = json_decode($a);
$c = $b->AddInfo;
$createDivArray = array();
echo '<div class="style1">'; 
foreach ($c as $value){
   if (in_array($value->Title, $createDivArray)) {
      continue;
   }
   $createDivArray[] = $value->Title; 

   echo "<h4>$value->Title</h4>";
   echo "<p>$value->Info</p>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: I need for every same title display all the info in one div. Maybe in another record there is one or no accommodation title and multiple location or any Title.

Comment: May be so.

echo open and close dives outside from foreach

Comment: No AramGrig. Your code is displaying just the first one of multiple. I want to display in one div all $value->Info that has the same $value->TItle. Sorry if my question made you understand something else :D

Comment: Yes I do not get you. Sorry for your spending time

Comment: Thank you for your time really appreciate it. Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you have a nice day too